# SQL query to display year values which lie between two date values

Tags: sql

I am looking for a SQL query to display year values which are between two date values.
This is what my database looks like and this is what I need:

SELECT
ID,
StartDate,
DueDate
FROM dbo.Test

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzGeX.png)

Kind regards
Flixy04

I am looking for a SQL query to display year values which are between two date values.

Comment:  [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) [No attempt made](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: "I am looking for a SQL query".  Have you tried anything???  SO is not a free coding service website.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the range of year values, you may consider the following approach:

Create a secondary table with all possible year values, and then use a left-join query. In this case, the possible year values are 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025. Create a second table with a separate row for each of those years.

```
SELECT t.ID, t.StartDate, t.DueDate, yr.BudgetYear 
FROM Test t LEFT JOIN YearRange yr
ON DatePart(year, yr.BudgetYear) BETWEEN DatePart(year, t.StartDate) AND DatePart(year, t.DueDate)
```